# What are the name lookup rules for friend function name?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

According to [[namespace.memdef]#3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4618/namespace.memdef#3):

> If a `friend` declaration in a non-local class *first declares* a class, function, class template or function template the friend is a member of the innermost enclosing namespace.

I think the compiler has to perform name lookup to determine if the friend declaration *first declares* a function. That is, the compiler will try to find the entity corresponding to the `friend` declaration. But I didn't find anything in the standard describing that lookup rule.

The text following the above in the standard says

> If the name in a friend declaration is neither qualified nor a template-id and the declaration is a function or an elaborated-type-specifier, the lookup to determine whether the entity has been previously declared shall not consider any scopes outside the innermost enclosing namespace.

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/unqualified_lookup):

> For a friend declaration, the lookup to determine whether it refers to a previously declared entity proceeds as *above* except that it stops after the innermost enclosing namespace.

where "above" refers to the lookup rules for unqualified names in class definitions.

So I wrote a small example to test my idea:

```cpp
struct A {
  static void fun(A) { }
  friend void fun(A);
};

fun(A{});
```

Here the call to `fun` will find the `friend` function `fun` within the `struct A` via ADL. I tested the code on clang and it throws a linker error([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/noE4PqYPd)):

> undefined reference to `fun(A)'

This proves that the friend function `fun` is not related to the static member function `fun`.

However, according to cppreference, the name `fun` should be looked up within the class first. I don't know why the static member `fun` cannot be found here. Well, I agree that this is a ridiculous explanation, but I can't find a standard text that refutes that explanation.

So what rules does the compiler follow to find the entity corresponding to the friend declaration?

Comment: This was CWG138 resolved by [P1787](http://wg21.link/p1787): «If the declaration is a friend declaration … Otherwise [declarator-id is neither a qualified-id nor a template-id], the terminal name of E is not looked up. The declaration’s target scope is the innermost enclosing namespace scope»

Comment: @LanguageLawyer That looks like it could be posted as an answer.